# How To Manage Meteor App Running On AWS AMAZON EC2

Tags: mongodb, meteor, amazon-ec2

I've deployed my Meteor App to AWS AMAZON EC2 in order to test my app in that environment including the newly configured domain name redirection etc...

Things did not work out perfectly when I tried to register a new user and when I tried to verify the email of the new user.

Given this scenario, I would like to `reset` the project or `reset` the users Collections in the mongodb of that Meteor App. Since I would like to be abel to reuse that email I use for testing.....

In my computer, when I encounter this problem I conveniently enter this command in my project's folder and I get the mongoldb reset:

```
meteor reset
```

How do I find where the app is in the EC2 instance the Meteor app is contained in???

After I ssh to the IP address with the paired key, I am allowed access to the instance, but when I do a `ls` I get nothing and don't know where to start....I was hoping I could just do a `meteor reset` or find where the mongodb is within that instance and delete the fields or collections I would like to delete.....

How do I achieve this?
How does one manage a Meteor app within this kind of environment such as AWS AMAZON EC2??

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to the "Accessing the database" section in `mup` docs.

https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#accessing-the-database

When logged to your EC2 instance, simply type `mongo appName` to access the mongo admin prompt.

Then you can use this command to clear the database in a similar way `meteor reset` would do :

```
db.dropDatabase();
```

Comment: Adding this for future readers...if u follow the above instructions, if u encounter the following error: Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.    All u got to do is something like: export LANG=en_US.UTF-8    before u do the mongo appName